# Android Force Close Uncatchable Unreportable

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, report

I've released my second game project on the Android Market this week, and immediately had multiple 1-star reports due to force closes. I tested it on many handsets and many emulators with zero issues. I'm completely at a loss for how to proceed and looking for advice.

I use Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler to intercept and report uncaught exceptions, then close gracefully. The people reporting force closes aren't getting to any of that, even though it is the first thing set in the application's main task constructor, and everything is wrapped in try/catches throughout. They are also reporting that there is no "Send Report" option in the force close popup (providing the Developer Console error reports), so I have absolutely no way of knowing what the problem is.

Uses Android 2.0, with android:minSdkVersion="5". Only Permission required is INTERNET.

(on Android market as 'Fortunes of War FREE' if you want to test)

Comment: when i get a chance i'll run it through the debugger to see what i get.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit surprised about the missing "Send report" button. What API level did you build the game with? I usually build the level with your minimum API level to make sure you're not using any API calls beyond that, but then switch back to the highest API level so you can use functionality like "install to SD".

I'm sure there's at least one user who wrote you a mail. Can you ask them to install LogCollector and mail you the log?

Btw, in general, I wouldn't use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` so there IS the option to send a report. (It's ominously missing in your case, but normally, it should be there.)

Btw btw, the exception handler applies to the current thread. If you have an OpenGL app, maybe the crash happens in the GL thread?

Comment: If you do it in your activity's constructor, then it will be in the UI thread. I would recommend building your app using at least API level 8, that way, you can enable "install to SD" (which you REALLY should do, your users will thank you). Just remember to switch back to API level 5 every now and then to make sure you're not using API calls that don't exist yet in 5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but as far as I know Android only shows that report dialog if you use its default UncaughtExceptionHandler.

Try this:
In your UncaughtExceptionHander's constructor, call `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` and save the returned object in a variable (let's call it defaultHandler). In your Handler's `uncaughtException()` do the things you want to do, and then call `defaultHandler.uncaughtException()` afterwards.

Maybe something you should know:
In my experience, your Context isn't functional anymore at `uncaughtException()`. So, you can't send broadcasts, etc anymore.

By the way, if you really wrapped everything in try/catch, that could be the reason why error reporting doesn't work as expected? :P

Good luck
Tom

Comment: So, you were able to start a new Activity in `uncaughtException()`?

Comment: Hehe, awesome idea! ;) Thank you!

Back to your problem... Are you sure you set your own DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler for every Thread? You need to set it every time you start a new Thread.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the force closes are caused by stalls, rather than exceptions. Users may not notice the difference. This kind of problem can occur more often if users have CPU hogging services running at the same time as your application, which explains why you're not seeing the issue in your testing.

Answer (score 0):

Permission Internet sounds a lot like you try to transfer data from the net, which is very fast in your local LAN, but all of a sudden becomes slow (and time consuming) when people try this over their GSM connections.

If you then do the data transfer in the UI thread, this one is blocked and the system detects the block - but then this should end up in a "Did not respond" -- but then I've seen one user report an error with in the market on my app that was such a slow down cause.